# SQLNative query returning empty results

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I'm trying to execute a query which needs 4 tables :

```
    @Query(value="SELECT e.* FROM erreur e, synop sy, synop_decode sd, station st WHERE e.id_synop = sd.id_synop_decode "
            + "and sd.id_synop_decode = sy.id_synop" + " and DATE(sy.date)= :date and "
                    + "sy.id_station = st.id_station and st.id_station= :stationId", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Erreur> recherche(@Param("date") Date date, @Param("stationId") Long stationId);
```

This query works fine et native sql, i pass an existing stationId and  a date like the following :

```
SELECT e.* FROM erreur e, synop sy, synop_decode sd, station st WHERE e.id_synop = sd.id_synop_decode and sd.id_synop_decode = sy.id_synop
            and DATE(sy.date)= '2019-05-27' and sy.id_station = st.id_station and st.id_station= 60355;
```

This query works fine in Mysql Workbench.

Here's the actual controller i'm using for testing purpose :

```
@GetMapping("/station/{stationId}/erreurs/today")
    public List<Erreur> getTodayErreurByStationId(@PathVariable Long stationId)
    {
        List<Erreur> erreurs = new ArrayList<Erreur>();
        Optional<Station> stationOptional = stationRepository.findById(stationId);
        if(stationOptional.isPresent())
        {
            return erreurRepository.recherche(new Date(), stationId);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The expected results are the actual "Ererur" objects in my array list, but RestClient just returns an empty array [], while the query works just fine in mysql like i described it above.

So my question is : How can i write this query into Hql language so that i can return the right entities. Or how can i map my sql results to my target custom calss "Erreur"?

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="erreur")
public class Erreur {

    public Erreur(int section, int groupe, String info) {
        this.section = section;
        this.groupe = groupe;
        this.info = info;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_erreur")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
    fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="id_synop")
    private SynopDecode synopDecode;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_controle")
    private Controle controle;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="id_station")
    private Station station;

    @Column(name="section")
    private int section;

    @Column(name="groupe")
    private int groupe;

    @Column(name="info")
    private String info;
}
```

Comment: Please show relation between `SynopDecode` and `Synop`

Comment: Can you run this without the Date param ? Date equality may be not giving what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jpa methods by conventions.
Assuming `SynopDecode` has property like:

```java
//SynopDecode class

@ManyToOne
private Synop synop;
```

```java
//repository interface

List<Erreur> findByStationIdAndSynopDecodeSynopDate(Long stationId, Date date);
//or
//List<Erreur> findByStationIdAndSynopDecode_Synop_Date(Long stationId, Date date);
```

**UPDATE**
As Punit Tiwan (@punit-tiwan) note that, the above methods used for a specific datettime.
You can use methods below for just DATE.

```java
//repository interface

List<Erreur> findByStationIdAndSynopDecodeSynopDateBetween(Long stationId, Date startOfDate, Date endOfDate);
//or
//List<Erreur> findByStationIdAndSynopDecode_Synop_DateBetween(Long stationId, Date startOfDate, Date endOfDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jpa convention directly then you will have to make associations between different entities i.e. how two entities are linked. When we define these associations then spring jpa knows how to convert method name or custom queries into SQL.

Your code will need to be something like

```
public class Erreur {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns//define how Erreur and SynopeDecone are linked
private SynopDecode synopDecode;
...
```

```
public class SynopDecode {
...
@ManyToOne // or @OneToOne its not mentioned in question how these two are linked
@JoinColumns//define how SynopDecode and Synop are linked
private Synop synop;
...
```

Then you can write your query like

```
@Query("select e from Erreur e LEFT JOIN e.synopDecode sy LEFT JOIN sy.synop sy WHERE DATE(sy.date) = :date AND sy.id_station = :stationId")
List<Erreur> getByDateAndStationId(@Param("date") Date date, @Param("stationId") Long stationId)
```

You can't use method name based query because you want to use SQL function to match only "date" part of your date and not the whole timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to get the same results as my SQL Query using the @Query annotation and accessing object properties like this :

```
    @Query("from Erreur e where e.synopDecode.synop.station.id = :stationId and "
            + "DATE(e.synopDecode.synop.date) = :date")
    public List<Erreur> recherche(@Param("date") Date date, @Param("stationId") Long stationId);
```

I think it solves my problem, thanks for the help